# Cannot understand Antlr tool error parsing grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr2

```
// Parser
statement
    : DELIMITER* statementPart+ DELIMITER* (EOL { newline(); })?
    ;

// Lexer
DELIMITER
    : ';'
    ;


sql-stmt.g:85:13: rule classDef trapped:
sql-stmt.g:85:13: unexpected token: DELIMITER
```

Line 85 is the `statement` rule.  I really have no idea why this fails.  Please help?

This is with Antlr2 btw.  Yes, yes, super old, yes, yes...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Been playing with Antlr4 too much :)  In Antlr2 I guess tokens / rules have to be wrapped in parens to apply `*` or `+` or ...

Comment: Haha, nice! That might also explain why I see parenthesised single tokens in v3 or even v4 grammars: these might very well have been ported from v2 grammars.

Comment: Thanks Bart.  Even worse, I am trying to back-port some work we did using Antlr 4 to stuff using Antlr2 lol.  Since you are extremely knowledgeable with Antlr, if you have time would you be willing to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821211/negated-lexer-rules-tokens?  Its related to this same work.  Thanks :)

Comment: Not much free time ATM and I've never done much with ANTLR v2, but if your question isn't answered by Sunday, I'll see if I can get v2 running on my machine.